# MVC con Ajax error no pasa el id

Tags: ajax, php7, pdo

a ver si me pueden dar una mano con este problema, no me pasa el id del producto para ser modificado en la base de datos. Estoy usando Ajax y el formulario lo tengo en un modal, al hacer clic en el botón editar, me carga bien los campos del formulario, pero por alguna razón que no logro ver, no me pasa el id.

Paso a mostrarles el código:

Modal, pongo solo el formulario que esta en el body.

```
  <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" id="idCategoria1" name="id" value="">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>Categoría</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre1" class="form-control" id="categoria1" 
value="">
            <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="empresa1" class="form-control" value="" 
id="empresa1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="btnEditar1" value="Editar 
Categoría">
        </div>

  </div>
```

Va el código ajax:

```
$('#tablaCategorias tbody').on('click','.btnEditar',function(){

$("#Modal1").modal('show');
var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
accion ="actualizar";

$("#idCategoria1").val(data["id"]);
$("#categoria1").val(data["nombre"]);
$("#empresa1").val(data["empresa"]);

$("#btnEditar1").on('click',function(){
    var id = $("#idcategoria1").val(), 
    nombre = $("#categoria1").val(),
    empresa = $("#empresa1").val();

var datos = new FormData();
datos.append('idCategoria1',id);
datos.append('nombre1',nombre);
datos.append('empresa1',empresa);
datos.append('accion',accion);

Swal.fire({
title: 'Está seguro de Editar la categoría?',
icon: 'warning',
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar!',
cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar!',
}).then((result) => {
if (result.isConfirmed) {
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/categorias.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(respuesta){
//console.log(respuesta);  
Toast.fire({
   icon: 'success',
   title: respuesta
});
        
        $("#Modal1").modal('hide');
        table.ajax.reload(null,false);
        $("#categoria1").val("");
        $("#nombre1").val("");
        $("#empresa1").val("");
       }
     });        
    }
  })
  })
  })
```

Y por último el archivo categorias.ajax.php

```
if($_POST["accion"] == "actualizar"){   
$actualizar = new ajaxCategorias();
$actualizar->id = $_POST["idCategoria1"];
$actualizar->nombre = $_POST["nombre1"];
$actualizar->empresa = $_POST["empresa1"];
$actualizar->actualizarCategorias();
```

No se si necesitan que les pase mas info, espero que me puedan ayudar asi sigo adelante con este proyecto. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: listo resuelto el problema